# how to compare elements of a lists in prolog

Tags: prolog

how do you compare two lists to see if then are different

```
?- compare_lists(X,Y).
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

What about as follows ?

```
compare_list([], []).

compare_list([H1 | T1], [H2 | T2]) :-
  H1 \= H2,
  compare_list(T1, T2).
```

This require that both lists have the same length to return true; if you want true also from list of different length, you have to double the ground case of the recursion, so instead

```
compare_list([], []).
```

you can write

```
compare_list([], _).

compare_list(_, []).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [**`maplist/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3) here with [**`(\=)`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%5C%3D)/2) as the goal:

```
compare_list(LA, LB) :-
    maplist((\=), LA, LB).
```